# How to display a dictionary on an html page with flask?

Tags: python, flask

How to display a dictionary on an html page with flask? Sorry for the stupid question, I can't find a good example of both an html page and a python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backend

```
@app.route('/')
def print_dict():
    d = {'hello': 'world'}
    return render_template('base.html', d=d)
```

base.html:

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in d.items() %}
    <li>{{ key }}: {{ value}} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```